# Add defined string to last column of data

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 tables which I am comparing. For the identifiers which don't appear in sheet 2 that are in sheet 1 are being copied to another sheet.

For these rows of data i am trying to add a column headed "missing from" and insert "missing from sheet 2" in column at the end of the row of data

e.g. current sheet looks like:

```
i.d    | Department| Sales | Date
1      | i.t       | 100   | 01/01/2015
2      | i.t       | 200   |
```

i want:

```
i.d    | Department| Sales | Date       |Missing
1      | i.t       | 100   | 01/01/2015 |from sheet 2
2      | i.t       | 200   |            |from sheet 2
```

This is my current code (which copies over all the rows which are missing):

```
  'ID missing from sheet 2
        id.EntireRow.Copy
        missingids.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set missing_output = missingids.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify what you want, if an ID is in sheet 1 but not in sheet2 you want to copy the ID and row details from sheet 1 into a separate sheet and add an extra column called `missing` with the description `from sheet 2`?

Comment: @Alex P yes that's correct

Comment: Are you using **Tables** or just cells?

Comment: @Raystafarian I don't quite understand your question. since  the data is always changing, I am comparing sheet 1 to sheet 2. I am searching the I.D column to see if the ID exists in sheet 2, if it does not exist then i am copying that entire row of data from sheet 1 to sheet 3. In sheet 3 at the end of the row under the header "missing" I want to display "missing from sheet 2". I hope this answers your question, thanks.

Comment: You said you're using tables, but your VBA is not using table notation. Are they actually table objects, or just cells (rows, columns) that appear to be a table.

Comment: @Raystafarian I understand what you mean, yes there are just cells (rows and columns)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you get started. This code works as follows:

1. Iterate over the IDs in `sheet1` and check if not found in `sheet2`
2. If not found, copy data for that ID into columns A to D in `sheet3`
3. In column E add `"from sheet 2"`

Change the code to suit your needs.

```
Sub CopyMissingRows()
    Dim idMasterList As Range, idCompareList As Range, id As Range, found As Range, rw As Integer

    Set idMasterList = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")
    Set idCompareList = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A10")
    rw = 2

    For Each id In idMasterList
        Set found = idCompareList.Find(What:=id, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If found Is Nothing Then

            With Worksheets("Sheet3")
                .Range("A" & rw) = id              ' ID
                .Range("B" & rw) = id.Offset(0, 1) ' Department
                .Range("C" & rw) = id.Offset(0, 2) ' Sales
                .Range("D" & rw) = id.Offset(0, 3) ' Date
                .Range("E" & rw) = "from sheet 2"  ' Missing
            End With

            rw = rw + 1
        End If
    Next id
End Sub
```